# Failed to Execute Simple "Select" Query using SQLITE in Android?

Tags: java, android, select, android-sqlite

Here is Select Query.Every Time  i am getting error :

```
SELECT 
       mf.id, 
       mf.field_type_id, 
       mf.field_label, 
       mf.field_values as mf_values,
       mf.is_required, 
       sfv.field_value as sfv_Value 
FROM menu_fields mf 
LEFT OUTER JOIN site_field_values sfv 
ON mf.id=sfv.menu_fields_id 
AND sfv.proposal_id=100000 WHERE mf.menu_id=2;
```

Here is the **Logcat**:

```
02-06 22:36:05.010: E/SQLiteLog(27524): (1) near "mf": syntax error
02-06 22:36:05.015: D/AndroidRuntime(27524): Shutting down VM 02-06
22:36:05.015: W/dalvikvm(27524): threadid=1: thread exiting with
uncaught exception (group=0x41bdf2a0) 02-06 22:36:05.030:
E/AndroidRuntime(27524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-06 22:36:05.030:
E/AndroidRuntime(27524): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near
"mf": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT
mf.id,mf.field_type_id,mf.field_label,mf.field_values as mf_values
mf.is_required, sfv.field_value as sfv_Value FROM menu_fields mf LEFT
OUTER JOIN site_field_values sfv ON mf.id=sfv.menu_fields_id AND
sfv.proposal_id=100000 WHERE mf.menu_id=2 02-06 22:36:05.030:
E/AndroidRuntime(27524): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
Method) 02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1012)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37) 02-06
22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.db.SiteCRUD.getAllSite(SiteCRUD.java:71)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.activities.fragments.SiteFragmentActivity.onCreateView(SiteFragmentActivity.java:51)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 02-06
22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 02-06
22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-06 22:36:05.030: 
E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898) 02-06
22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-06
22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-06 22:36:05.030:
E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-06 22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773) 02-06
22:36:05.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma between these two columns in your select clause

mf_values mf.is_required